# Mathematica ItemSize Disables SetterBar

Tags: dynamic, formatting, wolfram-mathematica, spacing

I am using *Mathematica* and have an issue with the `ItemSize` feature of `Multicolumn`. In my code below, I am generating a certain number of `SetterBar`s in the second panel based on the `SetterBar` value in the first panel. These programmatically generated `SetterBar`s update a list with values 0, 1, and 2. For Panel 1 values 2 and 4, there is plenty of room. However, Panel 1 values 8 and 16 push the `SetterBar`s off screen. I tried using `ItemSize -> {5, 1}` after `Spacings -> 0` to "compress" the `SetterBar`s together. When manually setting the `ItemSize` feature, only the first `SetterBar` allows me to click and change its value. All other `SetterBar`s seem to be "disabled".

Can anyone show me how to "compress" the long list of 16 `SetterBar`s to all fit on a single row without the need to scroll horizontally?

```
DynamicModule[{ number = 2, list = {0, 0} }, Panel[Column[{
Panel[
 SetterBar[
  Dynamic[number, {(number = #), (list = 
       PadRight[{}, number])} &], {2, 4, 8, 16} ]],
Dynamic[
 Panel[Multicolumn[
   Table[With[{i = i}, 
     Multicolumn[{SetterBar[Dynamic[list[[i]]], {0, 1, 2}], 
       Style[i, 12]}, {2, number}, Alignment -> Center, 
      ItemSize -> {4, 1}]], {i, number}], number, Spacings -> 0]]],
Dynamic[list]}]]]
```

Comment: suggest you ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix the number of columns of the inner `Multicolumn`s to 1 and should not increase it with `number`.

```
DynamicModule[{number = 2, list = {0, 0}}, 
 Panel[Column[{Panel[
     SetterBar[
      Dynamic[number, {(number = #), (list = PadRight[{}, number])} &], {2, 4, 8, 16}]], 
    Dynamic[Panel[
      Multicolumn[
       Table[With[{i = i}, 
         Multicolumn[{SetterBar[Dynamic[list[[i]]], {0, 1, 2}], 
           Style[i, 12]}, {2, 1}, Alignment -> Center, 
          ItemSize -> {4, 1}]], {i, number}], number, 
       Spacings -> 0]]], Dynamic[list]}]]]
```

Or

```
DynamicModule[{number = 2, list = {0, 0}}, 
 Panel[Column[{Panel[
     SetterBar[
      Dynamic[number, {(number = #), (list = PadRight[{}, number])} &], {2, 4, 8, 16}]], 
    Dynamic[Panel[
      Multicolumn[
       Table[With[{i = i}, 
         Multicolumn[{SetterBar[Dynamic[list[[i]]], {0, 1, 2}], 
           Style[i, 12]}, 1, Alignment -> Center, 
          ItemSize -> {4, 1}]], {i, number}], number, 
       Spacings -> 0]]], Dynamic[list]}]]]
```

Both produce
[image: Out1]

You could also use `Row` and `Column` instead of `Multicolumn`.

```
DynamicModule[{number = 2, list = {0, 0}}, 
 Panel[Column[{Panel[
     SetterBar[
      Dynamic[number, {(number = #), (list = PadRight[{}, number])} &], {2, 4, 8, 16}]], 
    Dynamic[Panel[
      Row[Table[
        With[{i = i}, 
         Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[list[[i]]], {0, 1, 2}], 
           Style[i, 12]}, {2, number}, Alignment -> Center, 
          ItemSize -> {4, 1}]], {i, number}]]]], Dynamic[list]}]]]
```

[image: Out2]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!